Moderated Mediation Model with Three Moderators?
I'm trying to run a moderated mediation model with three moderators. I was unable to identify a model in PROCESS (Hayes) taht allows for this.
I've been told that it's possible in lavaan however, I'm having very little work.
Does anyone know how you could include three moderators for a moderated mediation model?
I was unable to find anything online!
Thank you!
# Create interaction terms
data$XW1 <- data$irs * data$asian
data$XW2 <- data$irs * data$black
data$XW3 <- data$irs * data$hispanic
data$MW1 <- data$ih * data$asian
data$MW2 <- data$ih * data$black
data$MW3 <- data$ih * data$hispanic

# Specify the moderated mediation model
model <- '
  ih ~ a*irs + am1*XW1 + am2*XW2 + am3*XW3
  dep ~ c*irs + b*ih + bm1*MW1 + bm2*MW2 + bm3*MW3 + cp1*asian + cp2*black + cp3*hispanic
  indirect := a*b
  total := c + (a*b)
'

I don't know if what I've attempted above is accurate.

Are they three moderators? Or are they dummy variables repressenting one categorial moderator with four groups?
